# I can't change tag class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a navigation panel. I want the class of the menu item to change to `active` if I click on it.

```
%li= { :class => current_page?(admin_roles_path) ? 'active' : nil }
    = link_to "Roles", admin_roles_path
```

But I get the following error:

```
Haml::SyntaxError in Admin::Roles#index
Showing /sites/freshapp/app/views/layouts/_sidebar.html.haml where line #7 raised:

Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %li and nested within it.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `=` after your `%li` and you have too mush spaces / tabs. (Haml is a nested language, number of tabs / spaces matters). Do this:

```
%li{ :class => current_page?(admin_roles_path) ? 'active' : nil }
  = link_to "Roles", admin_roles_path
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (you don't need `=` after `%li`)

```
%li{ :class => current_page?(admin_roles_path) ? 'active' : nil }
  = link_to "Roles", admin_roles_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
%li{ :class => "#{current_page?(admin_roles_path) ? 'active' : nil}"}
  = link_to "Roles", admin_roles_path
```